# How do I figure out why errors are occurring when running unit tests on app that is being upgraded from Rails 2.3 to Rails 3.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-3-upgrade

I've been tasked with upgrading an app from Rails 2.3.5 to 3.0.19.  This also involves upgrading Ruby from 1.8.6 to 1.8.7.  After this upgrade is complete and stable, the plan is then to move to Ruby 1.9 and Rails 3.2.

Gems (output from `bundle install`), fyi:

```
Using rake (10.0.3)
Using abstract (1.0.0)
Using activesupport (3.0.19)
Using builder (2.1.2)
Using i18n (0.5.0)
Using activemodel (3.0.19)
Using erubis (2.6.6)
Using rack (1.2.7)
Using rack-mount (0.6.14)
Using rack-test (0.5.7)
Using tzinfo (0.3.35)
Using actionpack (3.0.19)
Using mime-types (1.19)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.12)
Using mail (2.2.19)
Using actionmailer (3.0.19)
Using arel (2.0.10)
Using activerecord (3.0.19)
Using activeresource (3.0.19)
Using highline (1.6.15)
Using net-ssh (2.6.2)
Using net-scp (1.0.4)
Using net-sftp (2.0.5)
Using net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
Using capistrano (2.13.5)
Using color (1.4.1)
Using dynamic_form (1.1.4)
Using json (1.7.6)
Using mislav-will_paginate (2.3.11)
Using mysql (2.9.0)
Using transaction-simple (1.4.0.2)
Using pdf-writer (1.1.8)
Using bundler (1.2.3)
Using rdoc (3.12)
Using thor (0.14.6)
Using railties (3.0.19)
Using rails (3.0.19)
Using rcov (1.0.0)
Using rvm-capistrano (1.2.7)
Using verification (1.0.1)
```

There are errors that are occurring when running `unit` tests that I am unable to decipher or track down. The errors occur in tests against a class inheriting from `ActionMailer`.  They look like this:

```
1) Error:
test_email_to_list(EmailerTest):
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
    test/unit/emailer_test.rb:6:in `test_email_to_list'
```

Where the line referenced is just creating an email (`create_***` but now without the `create_` prefix for Rails 3).  There are no function calls that I can see anywhere nearby that are taking 2 or 3 arguments.

**BEGIN UPDATE to show relevant code**

The offending line in `emailer_test.rb` looks like this:

```
mail = Emailer.email_to_list('Subject', 'Contents', 'Code', 'Name')
```

and the `ActionMailer` method being called like this:

```
def email_to_list(eSubject, contents, list_code, name)
  subject    eSubject
  recipients ['email-list-' + list_code.downcase + '@mydomain.org']
  from       'fromaddress@mydomain.org'
  sent_on    Time.now
  bcc        ['admin@mydomain.org']
  content_type "text/html"

  # Old Rails 2 way
  #body       :contents=>contents, :list_code=>list_code.downcase, :name=>name
  # Rails 3 instance variables
  @contents = contents
  @list_code = list_code.downcase
  @name = name
end
```

**END UPDATE to show relevant code**

**BEGIN UPDATE after making Mailer code more Rails 3**

I've updated the Mailer methods so that they look more Rails 3, like so:

```
def email_to_list(eSubject, contents, list_code, name)
  # Old Rails 2 way
  #body       :contents=>contents, :list_code=>list_code.downcase, :name=>name
  # Rails 3 instance variables
  @contents = contents
  @list_code = list_code.downcase
  @name = name

  mail(:subject=>eSubject,
    :to=>['email-list-' + list_code.downcase + '@mydomain.org'],
    :from=>'fromaddress@mydomain.org',
    :bcc=>['admin@mydomain.org'],
    :date=>Time.now)
end
```

That gave me another entry in the error stack output, but still nothing that enlightens me on how to resolve the issue:

```
1) Error:
  test_email_to_list(EmailerTest):
  ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
    app/models/emailer.rb:18:in `email_to_list'
    test/unit/emailer_test.rb:6:in `test_email_to_list'
```

(line 18 is `:date=>Time.now`, and commenting that out will change the line number in the error output to 17)

The issue appears to be occurring down in Rails guts between that `mail` call and the view being rendered.  `--trace` does not yield any more info.

**END UPDATE after making Mailer code more Rails 3**

I've been struggling for 2 days to figure out where these errors are originating and how to resolve them.  Any insight into how to troubleshoot further would be MUCH appreciated.

Comment: ActionMailer changed up its methods a bit. can you post the offending line in the test as well as the mailer method in your actual code?

Comment: This doesn't seem to address your 3 for 2 problem, but it looks like your mailer is still rails-2ish. You need to move the to/from/subject etc into a `#mail` method like http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-i-mail Also note that you need to call that method last so move your instance vars up to the top.

Comment: I'll think about the 3 for 2 more as well.

Comment: Adjusted, and that yielded one more line in the error output, but nothing illuminating :-( Also, i removed the reference to the functional errors, it seemed to wide a focus for the question - i'll ask another for that if need be.  Thanks again!

Comment: im not sure why this would be, but does it not like your concatenation in the `:to` value? Maybe try `"email-list-#{list_code.downcase}@domain.org"` I can't see any other place where there are 3 inputs...

Comment: Hmm, nothin.  I made all of the parameter values for the `mail` call simple values (no concatenation or variable substitution), and the error looks exactly the same :-(